# (Python)Transforming dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

My goal is to transform dataframe. Source and Target form is like this. And the date column of taget is index. How to transform source table to target form?  (I tried pd.DataFrame([sum(list(df.values()), []), but it doesnot work)

```
#Source form 
#date is 2021-11-24

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 20, 30],'B': [100, 200, 300]})

  A    B
 10  100
 20  200
 30  300


#Target form  (date is index)

# date        A0 A1 A2  B0  B1  B2
# 2021-11-24   10 20 30 100 200 300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
df_out = df.unstack().to_frame().T
df_out.columns = [f'{i}{j}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
df_out['date'] = pd.to_datetime('2021-11-14')
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   A0  A1  A2   B0   B1   B2       date
0  10  20  30  100  200  300 2021-11-14
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first pre-process the `df` using `pd.melt` to bring the column names down to the table under a new column called `variable`.

```
df_melt = pd.melt(df, var_name='variable', value_name='value')
```

Then append numerical suffix to the column names

```
df_melt['variable'] += df_melt.groupby('variable').cumcount().astype(str)
```

Now, it's a good time to put the `date` in,

```
df_melt['date'] = pd.to_datetime('2021-11-24')
```

so that I can use it as the index for my final table. `variable` is also set as the index so that I can use `unstack` to bring it up to the column names.

```
df_melt.set_index(['date', 'variable']).unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1)
```

The last `droplevel` takes care of the unwanted level of column name.